# Does Android TV Support AbstractAccountAuthenticator?

Tags: android, android-tv

I've implemented the AbstractAccountAuthenticator previously in an app for a handheld. I've been working on creating an interface and app experience for Android TV and wanted to be able to handle the user's account in a similar manner. I've created the implementing class and the service as well as adding the service into the manifest but I'm not seeing any account management area similar to the handheld experience. Google Music seems to be using some kind of account management functionality but I cannot verify that it is the same as using the "normal" method.

Does Android TV support this or is it not a feature of the platform and developers should roll their own?

Comment: Are you asking if Android TV has a system UI for users manually adding accounts or support for custom accounts in general (such as those programmatically created by your app)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake, I suppose I'm asking how one would accomplish the same UI interaction as on the handheld application for adding/managing account. After just creating stubs I was hoping to see a similar account management for launching an activity for taking something simple like username and password.